# Filter the record using input MONTH and YEAR but record still return current MONTH and YEAR

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on getting all the attendance record by inputting MONTH and YEAR to get all the attendance in that MONTH and YEAR. But I am having a problem that when I input the MONTH and YEAR, it returns the current MONTH and YEAR record. This is my function code below

```
public function getEmployeeAttendance(){
        $month = Carbon::now(request('attendance_date'))->format('m');
        $year = Carbon::now(request('attendance_date'))->format('Y');

        dump($month);
        dump($year);

        $emp_attendance = Attendance::whereMonth('attendance_date' , '=' , $month)
                                    ->whereYear('attendance_date' , '=' , $year)
                                    ->get();

        if ($emp_attendance->isEmpty() ) {
            return response()->json([
              'Error' => 'No record!!!.']);
        }

        return response()->json(
          [
            'success' => true, 
            'data' => $emp_attendance
          ]
        );
      }
```

When I use dd($month) and dd($year) it returns the current MONTH is "11" and YEAR is "2018", but my input in Postman is MONTH = "5" and YEAR = "2015" (the result should return empty record but it returns all current data).

Can you please give me some advises on how to improve this code. I use the same code from another function but it is not running when I write this to get the MONTH and YEAR inputted. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please elaborate what are your expected outputs against which inputs???

Comment: **1** what value are passing in `request('attendance_date')` and what do you expect from `dd($month)` & `dd($year)`   
**2** what data do you want in attendance???

Comment: I use dd($month) and dd($year) it returns the current MONTH is "11" and YEAR is "2018", but my input in Postman is MONTH = "5" and YEAR = "2015" (the result should return empty record but it returns all current data

Comment: what are the values of `request('attendance_date')`... If you are already giving month and year values from request, then why you need to use Carbon???

Comment: Just check for month and year using your inputs like:  `whereMonth(attendance_date, request('month'))` and `whereYear(attendance_date, request('year'))`

Comment: okay i will change to this. i will try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Option 1

> If your input is like this : 2018-11-12(Y-m-d)

```
$month = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', request('attendance_date'))->format('m');
$year  = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', request('attendance_date'))->format('Y');

dump($month);
dump($year);

$emp_attendance = Attendance::whereMonth('attendance_date' , '=' , $month)
                            ->whereYear('attendance_date' , '=' , $year)
                            ->get();
```

#### Option 2

> If your input is like this : 2018-11-12 10:10:59(Y-m-d H:i:s)

```
$month = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', request('attendance_date'))->format('m');
$year  = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', request('attendance_date'))->format('Y');

dump($month);
dump($year);

$emp_attendance = Attendance::whereMonth('attendance_date' , '=' , $month)
                            ->whereYear('attendance_date' , '=' , $year)
                            ->get();
```

for more info : https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

#### Option 3

> If your input is like this :

```
1. Input box-1 >> 10(month) 
2. Input box-2 >> 2018(year)


/* 
# No need those section.
$month = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', request('attendance_date'))->format('m');
$year  = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', request('attendance_date'))->format('Y');

dump($month);
dump($year);
# END
*/

$emp_attendance = Attendance::whereRaw("month(attendance_date) = '".request('attendance_month')."'")
                            ->whereRaw("year(attendance_date) = '".request('attendance_year')."'")
                            ->get();
```

Comment: i think i want to input the MONTH and the YEAR only (it will check from attendance_date) to get all the same month and year in that record. Like i input MONTH is 5 and YEAR is 2015, it will check the attendance to get the MONTH and YEAR of that record only

Comment: So you have 2 input fields (month and year) right ?

Comment: added "option 3", can you check it?

Comment: make sure your input name like this : attendance_month and attendance_year

Comment: i have did it. i change the Carbon::parse to request() in query.

Comment: Option 3 is the one i am looking for.  Thanks for your solution ^^

Answer (score 0):

use Carbon::parse instead of Carbon::now

Comment: i am trying to change from Now() to parse(). I will try this now

Comment: still cant. The Carbon::parse() dont receive the input, they receive the current DATE.